# How to mock providers/config in module config for unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-runner

I am trying to set up unit testing with Angular and have hit a bit of a wall with injecting into the module level config and run methods.

For example, if I have a module definition as such:

```
angular.module('foo', ['ngRoute', 'angular-loading-bar', 'ui.bootstrap']).config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, datepickerConfig, datepickerPopupConfig) {
```

Karma yells at me because I am not properly mocking $routeProvider, datepickerConfig, etc with the following:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module foo due to:
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeProvider
```

(and then if I remove $routeProvider then it says Unknown provider: datepickerConfig and so on)

I also have the following code in a beforeEach:

```
angular.mock.module('foo');
angular.mock.module('ngRoute');
angular.mock.module('ui.bootstrap');
```

And the following in my karma.conf.js:

```
  'components/angular/angular.js',
  'components/angular/angular-mocks.js',
  'components/angular/angular-route.js',
  'components/angular-ui/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js',
  'app/*.js', // app code
  'app/**/*.js',
  'app/**/**/*.js',
  'test/app/*.js', // app.js
  'test/specs/*.js', // angular.mock.module calls
  'test/**/*.js', // tests
  'test/**/**/*.js'
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: Did you figure out how to resolve this. How to get the ui-router mocked? Please update the question and add answer if you could solve it.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure to include the `angular-route` module and all your dependencies into the `flies` array of your `karma.conf.js`. That should do the trick.

Comment: I edited the question above - I do have those includes in my karma.conf.js!

Comment: Just a sidenote, everything works fine when I remove the dependencies for $routeProvider, datepickerConfig and datepickerPopupConfig from my module.config block but obviously I do not want to have to leave that out in testing.

Answer (score 0):

> I also have the following code in a `beforeEach`:
>
> ```
> angular.mock.module('foo');
> angular.mock.module('ngRoute');
> angular.mock.module('ui.bootstrap');
> ```

I don't think you need to mock `ngRoute` and `ui.bootstrap`

Generally I just set

```
describe('myApp', function() {
  beforeEach(module('foo'));

  it('should do something awesome', function() {
    // arrange
    // act
    // assert
  });
});
```